# VB publish error

Tags: vb.net

In trying to publish a program I wrote, I select the desktop, in this case:

C:\Users\RossS1\Desktop\cpxtester\

Then on the last window before publishing, I get a window that says this it will be published to:    file:///C:/Users/RossS1/Desktop/cpxtester/

Looks like a web-type path, not a Windows, but anyway when I click Publish, I get a blank web page opened that says "This webpage is not found".

So, although I specified that the file will be installed by users from a CD/DVD it looks like it's trying to publish to a web page.  I can't seem to change this and therefore can't create an executable.  D'oh!
i

Comment: Why do you need to publish a Windows application? If you compile Release version, it's pretty much ready to go

Comment: You create an executable by building your project. Every time you do so, it creates an executable that's placed in either the `Release` or `Debug` folder for your project (beneath the `bin` folder). You don't need to deploy in order to "create an executable". Publishing is typically used for putting a web site or web application on a remote server.

Comment: Briefly, the 'publish' option in Visual Studio builds a ClickOnce deployment of your application. If you want to deploy using a .msi file then you need to create a 'setup and deployment' project. (This option seems to have gone missing in VS2012) Finally as Yuriy says, the exe is *pretty much* ready to go (where 'pretty much' = depending on required dlls, versions of the .Net framework etc)